# jsonp with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Can you give a very simple example of reading a jsonp request with jquery? I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Here is working example:

```
<html><head><title>Twitter 2.0</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<div id='tweet-list'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets) {
        for(i in tweets) {
            tweet = tweets[i];
            $("#tweet-list").append(tweet.text + "<hr />");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Notice the `?callback=?` at the end of the requested URL. That indicates to the `getJSON` function that we want to use JSONP. Remove it and a vanilla JSON request will be used. Which will fail due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can find more information and examples on the JQuery site: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I was trying out $.ajax with those jsonp parameters and could not get that to work. Anyway, this works nicely, thanks.

Comment: Does the `?callback=?` actually get sent as part of the URL or is it just a kind of flag that jQuery sees and the strips off before fetching the URL?

Comment: What is necessary if your URL requires parameters?   (ex: `?p=1&s=50`)

Comment: I found this to be a good reference as a starting point. To answer above: Yes, the callback does get sent as a parameter and should be sent back as a function wrapped around the JSON response. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token. To send additional parameters they are sent in the second parameter of the getJSON(), in the above ex. replace null with {p:1,s:50}

Comment: I get error code 410 - gone. Is there an "eternally" present service returning JSON anywhere? Just so one can test that the own method works?

Comment: i ran you code in my chrome browser and its showing following error in console :Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < .....FYI its also showing syntax error(<!DOCTYPE html>) in firefox.

Comment: Konrad: Twitter's API changes have been big news lately; they're shutting out some of their old, open services and forcing people to register to see data.  [There's a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292050/is-there-any-public-accesible-json-data-source-to-test-treeview-user-control) like yours that used to point to Twitter.  I've since added the Tumblr API, which looks like `http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json`.

Comment: JSONP

If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Comment: How do you make the php side of this to call the callback function when it doesn't have a name?