# accessing JSON in external server

Tags: jquery, json

I have external json URL.

http://kun6858.iptime.org:8080/apps/list/?app_mb_no=9

And I access this json with jquery $.getJSON(..)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.getJSON(
    "http://kun6858.iptime.org:8080/apps/list/?jsoncallback=?",
    {
        app_mb_no : 9
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I can't access the JSON using above source.

I have no idea about how to access external server's json.
Does my source have problem? or the JSON?

---

for your reference, this is screen shot..

[image]

Comment: This was secret of Jquery ajax..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JSONP for cross-domain access. Therefore, you have to modify your AJAX call.

An good explaination for this scenario is here:

http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Comment: tried with (function($) {
    var url = 'http://kun6858.iptime.org:8080/apps/list/';
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data : {
         app_mb_no : 9 
        }
    });
})(jQuery); this but the same...

Comment: Hi Patrick, does your Server Applikation Supports jsonp?
As seen in the Example you need to Wrap your jsonp response in the jsoncallback function.

Best regards,
Monsi

Answer (score 0):

Three points:

1. Doesn't `app_mb_no` need value in your ajax call? e.g. `app_mb_no : 9`
2. You can use the `.ajax` equivalent:  `$.ajax({
   url: url,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: data,
   success: callback
   });`
3. Have you run your code under a web server? You need to do this.

Comment: I tried it on my own server after your reply. but the same happened.. and modified app_mb_no : 9

Comment: go for javascript console, does it have something related to cross domain stuff?

Comment: i use chrome and it give me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Comment: I believe the json doesn't have problem.

Comment: Check your JS code using chrome developer tool for syntax errors. Chrome will highlight them.

Comment: It's for Jquery's cross domain supports as long as I know

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how it works but this solved my problem.

Adding this in ServletResponse

```
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setContentType("Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8");
```

And the Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var url = "http://localhost:8080/apps/list/?app_mb_no=9";


if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
    // Use Microsoft XDR
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr.open("get", url);
    xdr.onload = function () {
    var JSON = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
    if (JSON == null || typeof (JSON) == 'undefined')
    {
        JSON = $.parseJSON(data.firstChild.textContent);
    }
    processData(JSON);
    };
    xdr.send();
} else {
          $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: url,
          processData: true,
          data: {},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) { processData(data); }
          });
}

function processData(data) {
    console.log(data);  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone knows better way please teach me!! thanks

Comment: For myself, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token