# Why JsonP doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, angularjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Does **jsonp** depend on server support, in order to return a correct response?

I got this request, and what I get back is js error.

```
$.getJSON('myURL?q=keyword&callback=?', function(data){console.log(data)});
```

even angular jsonp method isn't working:

http://jsfiddle.net/neoswf/tckGG/5/

*console >> js error*: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Does jsonp depends on some server implementations?

**SOLVED!!!**

This question is different from others cause no other answers speak about the proxy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server doesn't return JSONP, it returns JSON. A JSONP result is a JSON result wrapped in a function call.

Example:

```
callback873659823745({"destino":"http://...", ... })
```

If you can't make the server return JSONP, you would need a proxy server that requests the service and returns the JSON result wrapped as a JSONP result.

As it happens, I set up such a proxy a while ago, at [jsonp.guffa.com](http://jsonp.guffa.com), that you could use if you don't have the ability to set up one yourself.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/tckGG/6/

Comment: @Guffa- how can I write one of my own? If I'll be using your proxy, I'm afraid it might be too much expensive for you...

Comment: Never mind. Already found few tutorials on the web... http://blog.jsonpify.com

Comment: But how did you manage to bypass the Origin Policy using your proxy? After all I made a normal get request and got denied by their server.

Comment: @NeoSwf: Same-origin policy only applies to scripts executed in browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, jsonp requires server support.  The server needs to wrap the json in the "padding" part of the json**P**, which is a method that the client defines and executes around the response data.

Comment: is there a way I can bypass it? 
if not, and if the server have not implemented CORS, than do I got any option achieving my goals?

Comment: @NeoSwf: You have to use a proxy...

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling. Can you explain? How can the proxy will not invoke cross domain rules?

Comment: @NeoSwf: You have to run it from your domain, i.e. create an endpoint which accepts a URL, connects to that URL and returns the response to your script.

Answer (score 2):

Because your Url isn't returning JSONP. It is returning JSON.

```
{"destino":"http://www.buscape.com.br","palavras":["tv lcd 32","tv led","tv led 32","tv led 40","tv","tv led 42","tv lcd","tv lcd 42","tv lcd 26","tv 3d","tv lcd 40","tv 32","tv led 46","tv 42","tv lcd 22","tv led 32 full hd"]}
```

For an example if JSONP, check the return value from [flickr](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=callbackToExecute&tags=jquery&tagmode=any&format=json&_=1349909036208). It returns

```
callbackToExecute({... JSON Object ...})
```