# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing from browser-hosted JavaScript app to custom server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, user-agent

I am looking for a way to allow browser-hosted JS app to make requests to server running on different port and, possibly, different machine than that which is serving up JS app in the first place.

I am serving a simple JavaScript (HTML5) app from my Mac OS X Apache web server. I would like to be able to run this app in as many browsers as possible across Windows, Android and OS X. But I would settle for one on each.

My JavaScript app uses XMLHttpRequest to make requests of a minimal custom server that returns JSON.

So, for example, my JS app is accessible at `http://10.0.1.3/poc/dashboard.html`

and my custom server is running on same machine, listening on port 49379 ... a request like this `http://10.0.1.3:49379/find?name=Fred` would return a set of tuples where 'name' equals 'Fred'.

If I enter this request directly into navigation toolbar, then I get desired result.

If I make same request within JS, I get a couple of errors.

```
var theXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
theXHR.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateHandler;
theXHR.open("GET", "http://" + ipAddress + ":49379/find?name=Fred", true);
theXHR.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "XMLHTTP/1.0");
theXHR.send(null);
```

I get these two errors:

1. Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"
2. XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://10.0.1.3:49379/find?name=Fred`.
       Origin `http://10.0.1.3` is not allowed by
       Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I have control over Apache server, JavaScript and custom server. This is just a proof of concept piece that will be demoed on isolated networks. So, I am not concerned with security issues.

Also, I am running in Chrome, Firefox, Safari. All of these appear to use the XMLHttpRequest2 object.

Comment: Have you set the CORS header in the apache settings as well (or whatever your target server is)?

Comment: @scones. Thanks. No. I haven't. Where would I make modifications?

Comment: let this link guide you: http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way to get around CORS is to use jsonp - which is json with a callback function - I've never used it with XMLHttpRequest, but it works with jQuery ajax functions like `$.getJSON`. In your url query string simply add the parameter `jsoncallback=?` and voila, no more CORS problems. `$.getJSON` dynamically assigns its `success` parameter to the callback function.

Comment: thanks. I have been avoiding using jQuery in an effort to keep things simple. I feel the pull but would like to find another way, using XMLHttpRequest if possible - even if that means making mods to httpd.conf

Comment: After trying variants of 'Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *' and seeing no change in browser behavior, I adopted jQuery approach with callback=?. This complicated some of the path parsing that my custom server was doing, so I have gone to client-side 'named callback function' approach. This seems to have solved initial problem. Now I have some conflict in JSON serialization that I need to understand/fix.

Comment: Note that this approach results in JSONP (not JSON) result. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token for more info on this.