# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token with jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm doing an jsonp call to the following API : http://blockchain.info/ticker. I have been doing a good research on jsonp and i can't find what I'm doing wrong. In Chrome the browser constantly shows : 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'. Below is the code.

```
$.ajax({                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            type: 'GET',                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            url: 'http://blockchain.info/ticker?q=&callback=?',                                                                                                                                              
            dataType: 'jsonp',                                                                                                                                                                                                
            success: function() { console.log('Success!'); },                                                                                                                                                                                       
            error: function() { console.log('Uh Oh!'); },
            jsonp: 'jsonp'                                                                                                                                                
        });
```

Comment: That API doesn't support JSONP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are wrong in your returned json look at console in your browser, and replace `jsonp` by `jsonpCallback` and put your callback function name:

```
$.ajax({type:'GET',                                                                 
                url: 'http://blockchain.info/ticker?q=&callback=?',
                dataType:'jsonp',
                success: function(data) { console.log('Success!'); },
                error: function(errror) { console.log(errror); },
                jsonpCallback:'callbackName'             
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to jquery. Can you give an example of your callback function and where to put it. I'm running the call in an immediate function.

Comment: The callback function need not be anything you write. It will be just a name you give. Please go through what JSONP means and how it helps you. Check this out for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Answer (score -1):

That error is because you jsonp expect one function called "callbackName" then we already know is. Example:

callbackName()

and not callbackName: because is wrong

then you need return in server that

callbackName(data json)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, firstly thank you for taking the time to answer. Please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read [answer] to create helpful answers and add to the community.