# JSONP call showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/flight/AA/100/departing/2013/10/4?appId=19d57e69&appKey=e0ea60854c1205af43fd7b1203005d59&callback=?',
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        type : 'GET',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong? should I add or change anything in here?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: please remove space before  type : 'GET',

Comment: It's JSON, not JSONP on your url.

Comment: `async: false` doesn't work with JSONP. Why are you using `jsonpCallback` AND `callback=?` `crossDomain` is not needed for cross-domain requests (ironic isn't it?)

Comment: The API you are requesting from doesn't appear to support JSONP, that or you are using the API incorrectly for a JSONP response.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/repjt/

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/jsonp/flight/AA/100/departing/2013/10/4?appId=19d57e69&appKey=e0ea60854c1205af43fd7b1203005d59',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I had to manually set the callback to `callback`, since that's all the remote service seems to support. I also changed the url to specify that I wanted jsonp.

Comment: I find it extremely ironic that your username is "Jason P". :)

Comment: do you have to define a function named `callback` somewhere?

Comment: @ConnorLeech No, jQuery creates the callback function for you.

Comment: I actually get the same error as the OP with $.ajax as I do with Angular's $http, in my attempt at jsonp

Comment: I am still getting the error... :/ http://jsfiddle.net/w8e296zj/. I see it is only a JSON response hence the JSONP is giving the issue mentioned above. If I use JSON as a datatype, I get the CORS issue. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @Si8 - Yes finding same error. `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access`

Comment: If you're still getting the error, it's possible that the service doesn't support jsonp.

Comment: I ended up doing it through C# and it worked fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 18):

You're trying to access a JSON, not JSONP.

Notice the difference between your source:

https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/flight/AA/100/departing/2013/10/4?appId=19d57e69&appKey=e0ea60854c1205af43fd7b1203005d59&callback=?

And actual JSONP (a wrapping function):

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=processJSON&tags=monkey&tagmode=any&format=json

Search for JSON + CORS/Cross-domain policy and you will find hundreds of SO threads on this very topic.

Comment: All i have to do is specify JSONP in the URL as supposed to JSON as shown currently in the URL. Thankfully, the third party supports JSONP based on the link

Answer (score -1):

I run this

```
var data = '{"rut" : "' + $('#cb_rut').val() + '" , "email" : "' + $('#email').val() + '" }';
var data = JSON.parse(data);

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'linkserverApi',
    success: function(success) {
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log(success);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('Uh Oh!');
    },
    jsonp: 'jsonp'

});
```

And edit header in the response

> 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' ,  'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'
>
> 'Access-Control-Max-Age' , '3628800'
>
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'websiteresponseUrl'
>
> 'Content-Type', 'text/javascript; charset=utf8'