# return Json syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to display data returned as json data. but i am getting returned data as error.

here is my code:

```
  $.ajax({
     url:"http://excelonlineclasses.com/test.json",
     dataType: "jsonp",
     success: function(data){
         alert(data.facets.stats.total);
     } 
  });
```

i have tried `$.getJson` but it not works 
please find fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/6Yj5h/1680/

please provide me solution. thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"i am getting returned data as error"..?

Comment: please open jsfiddle link and see the console you can find syntax error. but it is valid json only

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't allow requests to external sites AFAIK. So better describe the problem instead...

Comment: I believe your demo is fine, and jsfiddle is fine.  I think the problem is that the url serves a json object, `not` a jsonp object.  See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: yes i t is json object only. when i remove jsonp i am getting cross browser excelption

Comment: I'm afraid you will not be able to retrieve cross-domain json unless the server is prepared to serve jsonp in the first place.  At least that's my understanding.

Comment: i am getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked error.any possible solution to get work done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ne1410s is correct:  the URL serves JSON, not JSONP.

You have three choices:

1. Get a URL that serves JSONP
2. Get the server to support CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)
3. Write your own server-side script that fetches the data, and then gives it to your script FROM THE SAME DOMAIN AS THE SCRIPT

I believe there's a fourth choice, but, honestly, it just gets more hack-ish from here.

To get the server to support CORS, you would want to add some stuff to the header, such as:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://excelonlineclasses.com/
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 10
```

...but it doesn't end there.  Browsers can send an OPTIONS request (in addition to GET or POST) to find out how the server feels about CORS.  The above is really what the server should return in that case.

If you want to set up CORS, I suggest reading something like http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: how Get the server to support CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

Comment: I edited my answer to give a brief example.  You really should check if there is a request for OPTIONS first.

Answer (score 0):

If you get  Cross-Origin Request  errors then you can set you header to allow cross origin requests In php you can achive this by addin this line of code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

(but make sure you actually want to enable  Cross-Origin Requests- * means from any site!  and you know what you are doing. In some cases for security reasons you may not want to allow this)

Comment: i understand is there any way to do with jquery

Comment: the header is set by the server