# Angular $http jsonp: how to parse through data

Tags: ajax, angularjs, api, http

I'm starting to learn Angular and I want to play around with the $http call function.
I basically want to make a get request to an external API:

```
angular.module('pokedexApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    var response;
    $http.jsonp("http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/1/").success(function(response) {
        response = response;
    })

    $scope.pokemon = response;
  });
```

I'm probably completely wrong as to how this works. I basically want to `{{ pokemon }}` out a response to test it.

I'm getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error and I can't tell if it's because the return data isn't properly formatted or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because in angular it will try to parse this response in json type. And it failed to parse, so it throw an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Seems in angularjs you'd better to handler jsonp response by your self.

```
  $scope.triggerJsonp = function(){
      $http.jsonp("http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/1/", {params: {'callback':'eqfeed_callback'}});  
  };
  window.eqfeed_callback  = function(data){
      $scope.response = data;
  }
```

[Here is jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/k413jf09/1/)

Relative issue in jquery.ajax [JSONP call showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) And answer use own callback to handle this.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for showing the relative issue too. Clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the website provides JSONP support - https://github.com/phalt/pokeapi_issues/issues/30

Your $http request is fine but you currently have a scoping issue with respect to 'response'. This is how your code should be written in order for your scope variable to be defined correctly:

```
angular.module('pokedexApp')
   .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.jsonp("http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/1/").success(function(response) {
            $scope.pokemon = response;
        })    
   });
```

Comment: I think you are wrong. I just try $http.jsonp("http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/1/") in chrome. And get a success response data from it.

Comment: I think the success response can be tricky/misleading. Are you able to actually get data from it?

Comment: Nice catch on the callback!

Comment: Thx. Here is another relative issue in jquery. [JSONP call showing “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)