# Cross domain HTML parsing using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

We are working on java project in which backend is java + spring and fronted is angular 2 + HTML.

I want to do cross domain html parsing but **we don't have permission to access external links on server side as we have some security issues for outsite domains**, so we have to get the DOM content of link on client side using jquery.

I have tried these:

```
var url = "http://xyz.aspx";

$http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: url,
    params: {
        format: 'jsonp',
        json_callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
    }
}).
success(function(response) {
    $scope.test = response;
}).
error(function(status) {
    //your code when fails
});
```

The external link which I need to parse contains many `href` links. I also need to parse content of those links.

Have tried above mentioned code:

> getting error in console - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on
>   xyz.aspx page

What will be best solution to get content of the pages and pass to server side for parsing?

Comment: Please bring some feedback, does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1)

> getting error in console - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on xyz.aspx page

This means that the server callback isn't a valid JavaScript application. Please ensure your server returns a valid JavaScript application. In that way this error will go away. `JSONP` needs a valid JavaScript application response to make it work. For example this is how a JSONP callback should look like:

```
jsonCallback(
    {
        sites: [
            {
                siteName: "Test"
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

---

#### Solution 2)

If your server side does not return a JSON Object try to use a `GET` request and enable [CORS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "http://xyz.aspx",
}).success(function(response) {
    $scope.test = response.data;
}).error(function(status) {
    //your code when fails
});
```

---

#### Solution 3)

If you are still be unable to add CORS to your backend you could create an PROXY application yourself. This for example is an public CORS Proxy https://crossorigin.me/. Adding an example on how to create a proxy service would be to much. Please research by yourself. There are a lot of examples in the web.

Comment: I can't change server content i.e. http link, I need only content from that server link.

Comment: @Geetanjali Updated, no way to make it work without having CORS enabled.

Comment: "JSONP needs a valid JSON body response " — It doesn't. It needs a JavaScript application, not JSON.

Comment: @Quentin, yes. but the `$http` method `JSONP` also works with an JSON object as response payload.

Comment: @lin — It shouldn't do. If you give it JSON in the response, it will generally throw an error when it hits the first `:`. JSONP works by generating `<script src="path/to/jsonp"></script>`. You have to feed JS into that, not JSON. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: @Quentin your are right, thx. https://plnkr.co/edit/3zM7wcm19Q8fbdc2dg7N?p=preview

Comment: @Quentin that link which I am using is html not json

Comment: @Geetanjali — Yes. That is why trying to prase it as JSONP doesn't work. I was pointing out that Lin's suggestion to change it to JSON would fail and that you need JSONP in the response.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, then what should I use to resolve this? and can you please tell me how my post can be duplicate if this belongs to html?

Comment: @Geetanjali for example: one of the solutions provided in my answer?

Comment: @lin not found any solution

Comment: @lin I am not able to get content from html page from your given 3 solutions and getting error- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @Geetanjali seems like you didn't even try one of the solutions given.

Comment: @lin I have tried and then respond you as my link content started from this <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> that's why this error comes again

Comment: @Geetanjali please join me in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137747/discussion-between-geetanjali-and-lin

Comment: Can you suggests me secure way to get content from third party domain link?

Comment: @Geetanjali Use SSL ;) and you will be fine.

Answer (score -2):

See [ng.$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#methods_jsonp). Your URL is missing the callback parameter,instead of giving like

```
 json_callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
```

Try below way

```
$http({
    method: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://xyz.aspx?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
    params: { name: 'xyz' }
}).success(function(data, status , header, config) {
    console.log('success');
}).error(function(data, status , header, config) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: I have tried these also, but I got same error.