# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" JSONP response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I make a JSONP request to server, from which I get application/json response.

My function:

```
  function testJSONP(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      jsonp: "callback",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

In Chrome console I get the following error message, and there's no output in console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I have validated my json response manually, and it's ok.

What could be the problem then?

Comment: What's the response in the network tab? Possible you're getting a parsing error due to a malformed response.

Comment: Doesn't setting `jsonp: "callback"` mean the response will be `callback(jsonStuff)`?

Comment: Your server has to return javascript, not json: `callback(json)`

Comment: @jfly response is valid json

Comment: So if I understand it expects javascript? Can I somehow expect json as response?

Comment: @pc9529 If you want to actually read the response, just do a normal Ajax request. JSON is not an Ajax request; it is when you load a script in a `<script>` tag, and that script is just of the form `someCallback({ "my":"data", ...})` and `someCallback` is already defined on your page to receive the data.

Comment: If you need to make the Ajax request to another origin (e.g., your site is `foo.com` and the site you want to reach is `example.com`) the site serving the JSON will need to [enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/). If you don't control that site, but you control any other server, you can have your page make a request to the server you *do* control. Then set up your server to do the fetch to the actual target and serve it to the page. (This is a "reverse proxy")

Comment: @bergi I see that this question is a duplicate, but definitely not to the question you have linked. My two cents...

Comment: @StephanWeinhold Well the question title of the duplicate may look as if it didn't fit, but I think I does a fine job at explaining the difference between JSON and JSONP. Could you suggest a better target?

Comment: @bergi Thanks for your answer! I think his question is client-side related. So maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token. Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165925/jsonp-call-showing-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token. But again: just my opinion.

Comment: @StephanWeinhold Oh, the first one is perfect indeed. I've added it to the targets

Answer (score 0):

Write like this...

```
function testJSONP(url) {
    $.getJSON(url,{},function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Comment: I need JSONP since the request is made to server that is on other domain, because of  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: Have you tried this? This code will get data from cross-domain too.

Comment: Yes, I did. It got me error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function testJSONP(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      jsonp: "callback",
      contentType: 'application/javascript',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I get same error after trying this