# How do i get data from a Labview web service restful with ajax or JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to to use `ajax` and/or `JSON` for Web service restful which I have build and deployed with the Labview software.

However I get errors (parserror)
For example. I have build a web service from a Labview vi (`z =x/y`    `localhost:8080/math/divide/5/20` will give `{Z:"4.000000"}` )

I get results when I run the web service with the browers (Chrome, Explorer or from Android application I have wrote) but I am getting errors for the below examples.

Below are 2 examples: `ajax` and `getJSON`

Does anyone know how to get data from the labview web service with `ajax` or `json`?
Thanks...Eran

- Example 1

  ```
  var url = "localhost:8080/math/math/5/20";
  $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      ContentType: "application/json",
      headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET"
      },
      url: url + '&callback=?',
  }).done(function (data,status) {
     alert(status);
  }).fail(function (data,status) {
     alert(status);
  });
  ```
- Example 2

  ```
   $.getJSON("localhost:8080/math/divide/5/20&callback=?", function (data) {   

   }).done(function (data,status) {
         alert(status);
   }).fail (function (data,status) {
        alert(status);
   });
  ```

Comment: If you expect people to help you you should take care that your questions are readable. What parsing error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery validates the structure of your json when you use getJson or ajax/get with parameter json. The problem is your key field in `{Z:"4.000000"}`. This is not valid json.
This is `{"Z":"4.000000"}`. Take a look here
[online json validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

What you could do (since you can access your json data from the browser) is test that data by pasting them in the online validator. When it marks it as valid make the changes you need.

**UPDATE**
After the clarification it seems that although you are asking for JSONP, you are returning JSON. Check this for more [json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: Update your question and fix the typo. Include some part of your json too

Comment: My proposal stands. Validate your json and check if it's ok.

Comment: The problem is not with the JSON. I get status = persererror. Ready state =4,status = 200...in the botto of the source I get the following line Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 20&callback=jQuery15109143281877040863_1378818328375:1

Comment: Check the update. If this solves your problem please don't forget to accept the answer.