# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : valid JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using this piece of code to get JSON data:-

```
 function getData(){
            $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "jsonp", 
            url: "http://localhost:8080/SpringFileUpload/service
/api/search?name=kop&query=java&smonth=0&emonth=200&key=7546323574194176&
zipcode=100001", 
            success: function(data) {
                    $("body").append(data);
                }, 
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.status);
                }
        });}
```

This is my json data which i am getting

```
{"took":"36","totalHits":"1","hits":[{"index":"kop","type":"doc","id":"L-elA3tKQYShys0Tv7WamA","experience":"86","providedName":"My name","providedPhoneNumber":"+96384545","providedZipCode":"100001","uploadon":"29/07/15","source":null,"url":"file://./Profile1_Java_SOAPUI_JUNIT 15.doc","highlights":[" TestNG. Experience with scripting using Java, Groovy etc\nExtensively used SoapUI to test Web",": Jira, MantisBT, QC\nOperating Systems: Windows XP/2000, DOS\nProgramming Languages: Java, C and C"," automated test plan for the application using Jbehave , Selenium WebDriver and Java.\n\nPerformed GUI Testing","\n\n Environment: Selenium WebDriver, Jbehave, Java, JUnit , Firebug, Jira, MySQL, Eclipse, QC,Window 7"," using Java and Selenium Web driver.\n\nUsed Jira for Defect tracking and triaging.\nUse Maven for build"],"title":"Professional Objective","contentType":null}]}
```

I checked this JSON data here

http://json.parser.online.fr/

It's a valid JSON data. But still my call is going to error. getting alert with 200 status and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in console. Please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

UPDATE:-

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sohc0gz0/)

Comment: Try `dataType: "json", ` instead of `dataType: "jsonp", `

Comment: @PranavCBalan If i use JSON then getting this error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Comment: And use `jsonpCallback: 'callback',`

Comment: then your response is invalid for jsonp

Comment: I all ready give you my JSON data which i am getting in response. It's valid. Thats why i cant understand why its going to error

Comment: add `crossDomain :true,`

Comment: Same error @PranavCBalan

Comment: Let me try to create JSFiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: @RenuThakur — It is valid JSON but you have told jQuery to treat it as JSONP, not JSON.

Comment: May be this will be your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: @soosmca — Hardcoding the callback name is a terrible idea. Let jQuery generate it automatically to avoid race conditions. That won't solve the problem of the server not sending JSONP in the first place.

Comment: May be response is not what jsonp call is expecting

Comment: @PranavCBalan — Why? The purposes of that is to tell jQuery, when it uses XHR (which it isn't because it is making a JSONP request) not to add the custom headers (like x-requested-with) which it only adds if making a Same Origin request just in case it gets redirected and accidentally makes a complex request to a different origin. It's not meeting either of the conditions where that would make a difference.

Comment: I just created JSfiddle. You can check there. Response is valid json data. But still it's going to error.

Comment: The valid jsonp response should look like `callbackname({"took":"36","totalHits":"1","hits":[..]})`

Comment: @RenuThakur — The error is expected. You are still telling jQuery that you are going to get JSONP and the server is still giving you JSON.

Comment: I tried with JSON, But after that i am getting cross origin policy error. Trying to solve cross origin policy from server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the error

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

you should add some codes in your **server**. Java version:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // ...
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    // you can change * for your spec url. 
    // if * is used, any url can be access to the data.

    // ...
}
```

and you can use `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: Ok. let me try this.

Comment: It's working. Working like a charm. Thanks.