# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token:

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  u r l: "exampl.com",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Amongst other things, you need to ask a question. Also, the full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. The question must be answerable without following the links, because links rot, and people shouldn't have to follow random links to help you.

Comment: May be a duplicate of [*json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token), as the OP says they really have `url` rather than `u r l`.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers in property initializers cannot have spaces in them unless they're in quotes:

```
$.ajax({
  u r l: "exampl.com",
//^^^^^----------------------------- Remove the spaces
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
});
```

Comment: Here's what I wrote with spaces

Comment: use `url` instead of `u r l`

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "exampl.com",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
});

Comment: @MarkPetrosyan: There are spaces in the code you put in your question. We can only work with the information you give us. If you actually have `url` rather than `u r l`, why waste everyone's time by putting `u r l` in the question? If you actually have `url`, sounds like this is a duplicate of [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token).