# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) solution. I have a similar error. But I didnt understand the first comment under 1st solution in it which says

> Thanks John. If I take the same code and point it to http://api.wunderground.com/api/8ac447ee36aa2505/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json' then the response does have the jQueryxxxx() wrapped around the json data, the code runs fine, and I get the 'Success' alert. I can't change the way the remote server serves up the JSON file. If I use dataType: 'json' then I get XMLHttpRequest cannot load isohunt.com/js/json.php?ihq=test. Origin localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

How to make the code point to the url he mentioned and how does this solve the problem? Any help would be appreciated. BTW, mine is a localhost url. I am working with retrieving data from elasticsearch and drawing google charts.

Comment: Are you using JSONP?  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` is a general error telling you that your JSON parse didn't work (probably because the HTTP response was not JSON.

Comment: Yes I am using jsonp. Else if I use json, it is giving me error similar to this -  If I use dataType: 'json' then I get XMLHttpRequest cannot load isohunt.com/js/json.php?ihq=test. Origin localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin (Referring from the link I mentioned in my question).

Comment: My basic idea is to draw a sankey diagram using data from elasticsearch query. I have data uploaded to elasticsearch. I am keeping this code as reference - http://pastebin.com/urjP8L6t . Any help would be appreciated. So, basically how do I check if json parse happened properly ?

Comment: I am also keeping this code as my reference - http://pastebin.com/uT0BTE4d . This error I was getting for this code.