# Sending a 'simple' POST request with jQuery, but getting CORS anyway

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

The CORS specification states that if a HTTP request is considered 'simple', no CORS and/or preflight is needed.

I'm trying to do a HTTP request that appears to have these conditions:

- I'm not setting custom HTTP headers.
- I'm using a `POST` method.
- I'm using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Code sample:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://example.org/',
  data: {foo: 'bar'}
});
```

However, when running this, the request is still preflighted with `OPTIONS` (which fails). Is there something obvious I'm missing?

A few references to simple requests:

- https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-cors-for-developers/#cross-origin-send-permissions-simple-safelisted-request
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests

Comment: I really would be interested in seeing someone give an example of an ajax POST with a payload not triggering CORS when the source domain is not allowed.  From my knowledge of the purpose of CORS, I cannot think of a case where this would be allowed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: @2by2 that's a dirty workaround. Would not touch jsonp with a 10 foot poll.

Comment: JSONP isn't for post requests anyway. I'd have no problem using JSONP for simple GET requests.

Comment: Is the server sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response? Even for simple requests, this is needed.

Comment: Hey @Barmar. It didn't, and you're right. I misunderstood simple requests in this case. The only difference was that preflight is not needed for them, but CORS still is. See my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

CORS restrictions affect all requests going from one domain to another. example: localhost -> example.com. I end up just going to my example.com server-side code and make sure I enable requests from myotherexample.com where I am making calls from. Do this using the CORS header while developing locally

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Another example when you are ready for production

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://myotherexample.com
```

Comment: Not according to the specification. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests

Comment: A request from one domain to another would have the Referrer header set, which I don't see as a whitelisted header in that spec.

Comment: Both TxRegex and Taplar are correct. There's no such thing as a simple request. You WILL always get smacked by CORS when making a request to a different domain.

Comment: This would only be true if jQuery _manually_ sets this header. Any protocol-level headers that a browser sets automatically would be excluded. Otherwise this wouldn't have worked before CORS was a thing.

Comment: Do you have any sources for that @Darkrum? MDN doesn't agree with you.

Comment: Are you suggesting that browsers are not implementing the spec correctly or that I'm reading the spec wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake when re-reading the documentation.

What I am doing is indeed a *simple* request.
The request was actually being sent to the server without an `OPTIONS` request and succeeded!

However, I was *not* allowed to read the response when it came back. So the true difference between simple and non-simple CORS requests is:

For simple requests a preflight is not needed, but the server still needs to respond with CORS headers.

So my options are as follows:

1. I ignore the error. The request succeeded after all, I just can't read the response.
2. I implement CORS server-side anyway. In my case I can't, because I don't control the target server.
3. I use a html form to submit the data, call `.submit()` on it and target a hidden iFrame.
4. I proxy the request through a server that I do control.

Future:

I *think*, but I'm not sure, that the new Fetch API also allows a mode where you can make HTTP requests cross-domain, opt-out of CORS and simply be denied access to the HTTP response. If this is correct, then this would be the ideal way to do this (to me). But I don't know 100% certain if this is indeed how this works.

Comment: I would expect #3 to incur CORS as well.

Comment: @Taplar eh, nah, it wouldn't. But you still wouldn't be able to read the response, you'd get access denied.

Comment: I guess I'm unclear on the difference between the two.

Comment: CORS doesn't help you access the contents of an iFrame. that's the difference. it isn't a cors problem, it's just a different but similar problem.

Comment: Yep and that's what CORS (in this case) prevents. Reading potentially sensitive information. Cross-domain form submissions were always possible.

Comment: So are you saying that using #3, the request would still go through at the target server, possibly changing things (since it is a post request), but you just wouldn't be able to see/access the response on the source server?

Comment: @Evert still don't know what your talking about. You still got smacked by CORS i refer back to my original comment "You WILL always get smacked by CORS when making a request to a different domain"

Comment: @Darkrum there is a such thing as a "simple" request when it comes to CORS. i'm not sure what you're getting at. Yes, it still has to support CORS if you want to avoid the error, but it'l still work, and is still quite different from a non-simple request.

Comment: But i will add this why are you making a request to a different domain you have no control over from the client and not making the request directly from your own server.

Comment: Because there isn't the spec can talk about simple requests all it wants but the FACT remains that some where during the request it WILL fail hence my response of "there is a such thing as a "simple" request"

Comment: except, there is, when talking about cors. A simple request differentiates from a complex one in that a simple request doesn't require a preflight. That's a pretty significant difference.

Comment: @Darkrum actually, the HTTP request does succeed. I'm just not given access to the response.

Comment: @Evert actually your HTTP request still failed spec wise and CORS still bit you. What you just experienced I already have. So your point is?

Comment: @Evert If I wanted to give a detailed answer then I would have posted a "answer" not a "comment" and I didn't waste anyone's​ time that's their own fault TxRegex already had the answer you just chose not to believe it. Now accept his answer.