# json request appends :2 causing syntax error

Tags: javascript, json, request

I am making the jsonp call shown below, basically an autocomplete. When the call gets made, a ":2" is appended onto the end of the url which causes an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :". The url is initially 
http://54.219.165.14:8086/AutoComplete?prefix=abc
and then the following gets appended to that to make the call:
&callback=jsonCallback&_=15072343456:2 
Anyone know where the :2 comes from?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#suggest").autocomplete({
   delay: 100,
   source: function (request, response) {
     // Suggest URL
     var catchUrl = "http://55.215.165.15:8086/AutoComplete?prefix=%QUERY";
     catchUrl = catchUrl.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

     // JSONP Request
     $.ajax({
       method: 'GET',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
       url: catchUrl
     })
     .success(function(data){
       response(data[0]);
     });
   }
  });
});
```

Note: this is not the same error as https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610. That was in the response. My problem is with the request.

Comment: I suspect it's from `request.term`. What is the value of catchUrl when emitted to the console after the replacement? Also, whatever is throwing the "Uncaught SyntaxError" is 'wrong' because, 'why are you trying to treat data as JavaScript' (is the *response* fed back to the JSONP callback *'wrong'* as well)?

Comment: It seems unlikely that it is from request.term. I did an alert to print that out and it comes out as a couple characters. Also the :1 is added at the very end of the string; after the extra stuff that json adds to the query. See the note before the code.

Comment: I got the code from this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/32Bck/. It works fine. All I changed was the url.

Comment: Good job. What was the change/fix?

Comment: The fiddle works fine, but my code does not. The fiddle uses this url: "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=%QUERY"; If I put that into my code it works, but my URL does not.