# $.getJSON not working with JSONP data

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery, jsonp

I am trying to do a JSONP request for data from http://soarforward.com/ClassDocuments, but it's not working.

If you go to the URL you can see the JSON. I am converting an ASP.net object to JSON myself, so if the javascript is invalid I can modify it.

Here is my example code :
http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/JDLqf/

```
function getFiles() {
    var url = "http://soarforward.com/ClassDocuments";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    getFiles();
});
```

Comment: Try adding this arguments to your $.getJSON() call:   dataType:'jsonp'  If it's still not working try adding:  jsonp: 'jsonp'

Comment: The sever does not seem to return JSONP. http://soarforward.com/ClassDocuments?callback=foo still returns JSON.

Comment: @paparush: Such options are only accepted by `$.ajax`.

Comment: @FelixKling - You're absolutely correct. I spoke too soon.

Comment: @FelixKling what do I need to do to my page to have it return JSONP?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JSONP) for details. The server has to return something like `valueOfCallbackParameter(jsonHere);`

Comment: @FelixKling That fixed it, I knew I was missing something to do JSONP. Can you tell me why this twitter example works but mine didn't? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery. From what I could tell, they don't have a callback function either.

Comment: I don't know the URL provided there does not work at all for me. But compare the different results of https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=codinghorror and https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=codinghorror&callback=foo

Comment: @FelixKling they used the same jquery method that I did with this url, http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json. It returns a JSON object without the callback, yet I am able to access it in this example without cross domain issues, http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/uD6ke/

Comment: I don't understand, in your example you are also adding `"?callback=?"` to the domain. That indicates that the server should return JSONP and then it does. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4761/discussion-between-guanome-and-felix-kling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to wrap my return JSON in a function call.

I was returning

```
{"foo" : "bar"}
```

instead of

```
fooBar({"foo" : "bar"});
```