# Is there any publicly accessible JSON data source to test with real world data?

Tags: javascript, json, testing, treeview

I'm working on a JavaScript dynamically loaded tree view user control. I'd like to test it with real world data.

Does anybody know any public service with an API that provides access to hierarchical data in JSON format?

Comment: StackOverlow itself now has a public JSON API for instance https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=perl&site=stackoverflow

Comment: check this tool http://json.live/

Comment: Teamtreehouse generates JSON data for all of their users.  https://teamtreehouse.com/matthew.json

Comment: this is [good site](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Comment: Try fakedata.dev which lets you access a million fake user accounts.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

<strike>[Twitter has a public API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) which returns JSON, for example -</strike>

A `GET` request to:

`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=mralexgray&count=1`,

**EDIT:**  Removed due to twitter restricting their API with `OAUTH` requirements...

```
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
```

Replacing it with a simple example of the [Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) - that returns a tree, of in this case, my repositories...

> https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos

I won't include the output, as it's long..  (returns 30 repos at a time) ...  But here is proof of it's tree-ed-ness.

[image]

Comment: It's not actually a tree, but since it's the only answer, i'm going to accept it) Thanks.

Comment: Umm, I think it is...  [looks like a tree](http://f.cl.ly/items/3v0v0Q0B2W233g371w15/Google%20Chrome.png), quacks like a tree, and works like a tree on http://jsontree.com/.  Must be a tree, no?

Comment: This is not public now... :(

Comment: I'm using Rotten Tomatoes movies json feed, but you will need to register and get a key (is free) http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/JSON

Comment: Another movies feed (needs as well free registration and ip key attached on each request) http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/ I used the rotten tomates, and planning to use this one for educational purposes.

Comment: @alexgray just wonder, what kind of soft it is on screenshot?

Comment: @shabunc it is called [Cocoa JSON Editor](http://www.cocoajsoneditor.com).

Comment: Even better, you can use Mockable.io for free to return whatever response you want. Example: http://demo4083160.mockable.io/getstuff

Comment: Reddit also has a public JSON api. just append ".json" to the end of any subreddit. Example: https://www.reddit.com/r/iosprogramming.json

Answer (score 42):

JSON Test has some

try its free and has other features too.

http://www.jsontest.com/

Comment: Getting an "over quota" error from their host.  Guess everyone found out about it.

Comment: Yup. The over quota error still exists. Returns a 503 -_-.

Comment: Still exists as of May 2016. At least you know you aren't getting a blank body, right?

Comment: It's 2016 and this has no HTTPS support, what the hell?

Comment: Doesn't appear to accept `POST` requests.

Comment: 2019, and still no HTTP support. Works great aside from that though.

Comment: 2022 and still no HTTPS support.

Answer (score 13):

Tumblr has a [public API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1) that provides JSON.  You can get a dump of posts using a simple url like `http://puppygifs.tumblr.com/api/read/json`.

Comment: There is JSON in the response, but what they actually return is JavaScript that initializes a variable with JSON. Their new V2 API returns "true" JSON but it requires signing up for an API Key or OAuth.

Comment: The old API supports JSONP in The Usual Way -- pass `?callback=foo` and you get `foo({...})` instead of `var tumblr_api_read={...}`.  The API docs don't mention CORS support so I strongly suspect most users would be loading the content via JSONP anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Found one from Flickr that doesn't need registration / api.

[Basic sample, Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Braulio/vDr36/)
More info: [post](http://richardshepherd.com/how-to-use-jquery-with-a-json-flickr-feed-to-display-photos/)

```js
// Querystring, "tags" search term, comma delimited
const query = "https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=soccer&format=json&jsoncallback=?";


// This function is called once the call is satisfied
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854250/understanding-cross-domain-xhr-and-xml-data
let mycallback = function(data) {
  // Start putting together the HTML string
  let htmlString = "";

  // Now start cycling through our array of Flickr photo details
  $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
    // I only want the ickle square thumbnails
    let sourceSquare = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_s.jpg");

    // Here's where we piece together the HTML
    htmlString += '<li><a href="' + item.link + '" target="_blank">';
    htmlString += '<img title="' + item.title + '" src="' + sourceSquare;
    htmlString += '" alt="';
    htmlString += item.title + '" />';
    htmlString += '</a></li>';

  });

  // Pop our HTML in the #images DIV
  $('#images').html(htmlString);
};


// Ajax call to retrieve data
$.getJSON(query, mycallback);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images"></div>
```

Another very interesting is [Star Wars Rest API](https://swapi.co/)

Comment: OOps, sorry I missed you were looking for hierarchical data, this is a flat source. I'm was having a hard time looking for public feeds without key registration needs and found this interesting to share.

Answer (score 2):

The [Tumbler V2 API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) provides a pure JSON response but requires jumping through a few hoops:

1. [Register an application](http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/register)
2. Get your "OAuth Consumer Key" which you'll find when editing your application from [the apps page](http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps)
3. Use any of [the methods](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) that only require an API Key for authentication as this can be passed in the URL, e.g. [posts](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts)
4. Enjoy your JSON response!

Example URL: http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/puppygifs.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=YOUR_KEY_HERE

Result showing tree structure in [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com):

[image: Screenshot]