# jsonFlickrFeed not defined when query flickr api

Tags: angularjs, flickr

I'm a beginer using angular js. It's been great so far though I got into this issue trying to query flickr public photos using their json api. Here is the 
[url](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json).

If you clck there you'll see the json response just fine. Though when I try to print the results on the template using {{flickrResult}} I only get {} printed, and when I check the console for errors I get "jsonFlickrFeed is not defined" which is part of the json that flickr provides.

Here is the code of my controller:

```
angular.module('Flickr', ['ngResource']);
function FlickrCtrl($scope, $resource){

$scope.flickr = $resource('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/:action',
    {action:'photos_public.gne', format: 'json', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
    {get: {method: 'JSONP'}});
$scope.flickrResult = $scope.flickr.get();

};
```

Any ideas how can I work around this?

Comment: I finally figured it out. Apparently I had to use jsoncallback instead of callback on the $resource call. That did it for me.

Comment: You can also do this with a promise which might be a better approach.

Comment: For those that are trying to get a result using raw JQuery, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Braulio/vDr36/ and this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292050/is-there-any-publically-accessible-json-data-source-to-test-with-real-world-data/20151543#20151543  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854250/understanding-cross-domain-xhr-and-xml-data