# Publicly accessible URL that will provide malformed JSON for development and testing purposes?

Tags: json

I've seen URLs such as those mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292050/is-there-any-public-accesible-json-data-source-to-test-treeview-user-control). These can provide well formed JSON and are publicly available.

However, I would like a public URL that will provide malformed JSON, ideally, in a variety of *bad* formats.

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Comment: Here's some pretty bad JSON: `ijm{4PcXXivnQLC,fH:pw]oDvBa5up,[SATzg2bW` :P

Comment: At the risk of sounding snarky, couldn't you just load *any* URL that isn't JSON? (E.g., http://google.com ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some JSON text files and put them in the public folder of a service like Dropbox.