# How to do external call in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This was working earlier today.  I'm not sure why it is broken now.  I'm doing the following:

```
$.getJSON( "http://ip.jsontest.com/", function( data ){  
    console.log(data);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rxykb0t0/

And keep getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ip.jsontest.com/. Origin
>   http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

If you look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/ZfvKm/2/, it is also doing an external call without issue.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just browsed http://ip.jsontest.com/ it gives error "over quota"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit http://ip.jsontest.com/ yourself, and see that the app is over quota. It looks like it's running on Google App Engine, so whoever runs `ip.jsontest.com` needs to increase their daily budget for that particular app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: @VladimirSerykh Google App Engine apps that are over quota don't respect your header settings as far as I know. So it's not an issue of configuring the headers (I would guess they're already configured properly), it's just an issue of increasing the app's quota.

Comment: ah - thanks.  Is there something more reliable just for getting back json test data?

Comment: @4thSpace From another answer, people have been using the GitHub and Tumblr APIs to get some real data to test with. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292050/is-there-any-publically-accessible-json-data-source-to-test-with-real-world-data