# Add option to select element using javascript or jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select dropdown box with one option entered.  I want to add additional options to the list using javascript or jquery.  I have tried multiple ways but nothing works.  Here is the html:

```
   <form class="form-all">
       <label for="selectStrategy" class="form-all" onChange="selectStrategy(this.value);">Select Strategy:</label><br>
       <select id="selectStrategy" width="400px" name="selectStrategy" margin-left="80px">
           <option value="new">New Strategy</option>
       </select><br><br>
    ...
```

Here is the javascript:
Attempt #1

```
function loadStrategies(callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/strategies", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.name);
            var select = document.getElementById("selectStrategy");
            var option = document.createElement('option');                
            option.value = item.name;
            option.text= item.name;
            select.append(option);
```

Here is attempt #2

```
function loadStrategies(callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/strategies", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.name);
            var select = document.getElementById("selectStrategy");
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(item.name,item.name);
```

Here is attempt #3

```
function loadStrategies(callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/strategies", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.name);
            var select = document.getElementById("selectStrategy");
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = item.name;
            option.innerHTML = item.name;
            select.appendChild(option);
```

I have also tried option.text instead of option.innerHTML

Here is attempt #4

```
function loadStrategies(callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/strategies", function(data) {
        console.log("strategies getJSON data=", data);
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.name);
            var option = "<option value=" +item.name +">" +item.name +"</option>";
            $('#selectStrategy').append(option);
```

In all cases, nothing is added to the select list and no errors in the console.  console.log(item.name) correctly shows the name that I want to put in the options.
Suggestions?

**EDIT**
Attempt #5

```
   function loadStrategies() {

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/strategies') 
        .then(data => {
        const $sel = $('#selectStrategy')
        data.forEach(({name})=> $sel.append(new Option(name, name)));  
        })
    }
```

Attempt #6

```
function loadStrategies(callback) {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/strategies", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.name);
            let option = new Option();
            option.innerHTML = item.name;
            option.value = item.name;
            $('#selectStrategy').appendChild(option);
            let row = $('<tr class="clickable">');
            row.append($('<td class="left">').html(item.name));
            row.append($('<td>').html(item.version));
            row.append($('<td> class="right"').html(item.total_return));
            $('#strategy').append(row);
        });
    });
}
```

In the above example, I include more stuff that is in the same loop but adds rows to a table.  It works just fine so why doesn't the part that adds items to a list work?:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadWatchlist();
    loadStrategies();
```

Comment: #4 has typo missing `<` in `+"/option>"`. Beyond that seems strange nothing is working. Can you provide minimal sample off data? Are you using any `<select>` plugins that modify default element into an html replica?

Comment: That missing < might be the only problem.

Comment: There are two items in the json data.  console.log correctly shows "sma-cross-and-extreme-hi-lo" and the next item correctly shows "sma-and-env_channel-crossover"

Comment: I fixed the missing < but same problem

Comment: Fine but if you provide as json we can run this. We shouldn't have to construct an array ourselves to test your code and make a [mcve]

Comment: The json is very long and wouldn't add any clarity to the issue.  As long as item.name is correct, that should be all that matters.

Comment: Well if it's too much trouble for you to mock up a sample what do you expect from us? There is nothing obvious in what is shown so far

Comment: Change your question to reflect what this is all about now.  And, read this https://json.org/example.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292050/is-there-any-publicly-accessible-json-data-source-to-test-with-real-world-data https://opensource.adobe.com/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to do that.  Thanks for the links.

Comment: Very basic working example https://jsfiddle.net/gchvp1f0/1/ Something is missing from what you are showing us. Perhaps the `<select>` doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed at how fast you did that!  Thank you.  I will try to rework my code based on your example.

Comment: I added your code as Attempt #5 but it didn't work either.  Attempt #6 adds more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add multiple options you must use loop

```
 $('#selectStrategy').append('<option value="'+item.name+'">'+item.name+'</option>');
```

Comment: Thanks for you input.  It is within a forEach loop.  But what I hadn't been doing is including the double-quotes inside of the single quotes.  Unfortunately, that didn't work either.  Argggg!

Comment: I finally found the problem!  I had another id in the code with the same id="selectStrategy".  I changed this one to id="selectStrategy2" and it worked.  I don't know if the double-quotes inside the single quotes also contributed to the solution but I will accept your answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. At least it did for me :D

```
let select = document.getElementById('selectStrategy');
let option = new Option();
option.innerHTML = 'Another new strategy';
option.value = 'new-strategy';
select.appendChild(option);
```

Comment: Note that `new Option()` takes value and text arguments which cuts this down even more

Comment: @charlietfl oh okay, but wouldn't it just create an option object with just empty value and text values? And later add those values? Im not that good at javascript :D

Comment: Sure, just simpler to do it when you create it is all I was suggesting. Example https://jsfiddle.net/gchvp1f0/1/

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it would just be two lines less in the code, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I've added it as Attempt #6.  I also added more details in that function which adds items from the same json structure to a table.  That part works fine.