# How to get proper JSON strings with double quotes using pd.read_json()

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to import JSON data including nested data, into a Pandas DataFrame. It is illustrated here using a nice little [public dataset](https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos) that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8654078/11542679). Let's focus our attention on the header `'owner'` for the purpose of this illustration. Note that I'm explicitly casting the data to `str`. If you print the response data from `response.content` it has the proper JSON syntax with double quotes.

However, [`pd.read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.4/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html?highlight=read_json#pandas.read_json) seems to convert the JSON string under `'owner'` into single quotes. Am I doing something wrong here or should this be raised as a dev issue in `read_json()`? I see a different issue relating to the single/double quotes has been fixed in the past on [pandas-dev](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15132).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get(url='https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos')    
>>> df = pd.read_json(response.content, orient='records', dtype=str)
>>> df['owner'].iloc[1, ]
"{'login': 'mralexgray', 'id': 262517, 'node_id': 'MDQ6VXNlcjI2MjUxNw==', 'avatar_url': 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/262517?v=4',..."
>>> type(df['owner'].iloc[1, ])
str
>>> response.content
    b'[{"id":6104546,"node_id":"MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk2MTA0NTQ2","name":"-REPONAME","full_name":"mralexgray/-REPONAME","private":false,"owner":{"login":"mralexgray","id":262517,"node_id":"MDQ6VXNlcjI2MjUxNw==","avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/262517?v=4"...
```

The only observation I make here is that `pd.read_json()` may be importing the nested JSON data as a Python `dict` before it is cast to `str`.

I'm running `Python 3.8.10` with `Pandas 1.2.4`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What output were you expecting instead, exactly?

Comment: It seems like you were perhaps expecting to see e.g. `{"foo": "bar"}` instead of `{'foo': 'bar'}`. Here's a hint: what happens when you try just `{"foo": "bar"}` by itself at the Python interpreter prompt? Another hint: what happens when you try `{"foo": "bar"} == {'foo': 'bar'}`? Or `"foo" == 'foo'`?

Comment: Yes, when the variable is a `dict` as in the case of `{"foo": "bar"}` and `{'foo': 'bar'}` they are equal. And the same goes for the individual strings `'foo'` and `"foo"`. However, my issue is with the content in the JSON string. `"{'foo': 'bar'}"` is not the same as `"{"foo": "bar"}"`. This becomes an issue for me later when trying to later use [`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.4/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) where I get `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:`

Comment: Yes, those are not equal strings. But right now you *don't have a string* in your Dataframe; you have a dict that represents the parsed JSON. If this somehow causes a problem "using `json_normalize()`", then you're going to have to show us a minimal, *complete* example. As is, what you show us doesn't *illustrate* a problem, even if you say there is one.

Comment: Not really, unless I have missed something here. I have tried to cast it to `str` when I call `pd.read_json()`. If you run `type(df['owner'].iloc[1, ])` it will return `str`. I will edit my question to make this clear.

Comment: Again, please show a complete example - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance. The output you show can't possibly be a real output; if the value really is a `str` then it would have enclosing quotes when displayed.

Comment: Sorry, I had made a mistake when copying the output code by dropping the double quotes - edited now. However, if you run my code you will see the output type as `str`. My code is however reproducible and you will notice the single quotes within the JSON string if you run it yourself. So as I said, I want to see something like, `"{"foo": "bar"}"` instead of `"{'foo': 'bar'}"`

Comment: I have 2 questions to better understand the context: in your case single quotes are an issue because you are not able to run `json_normalize()`? Do you need to cast the dataframe to `str` or it was just an attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: Single quotes are an issue because I expected `pd.read_json(dtype=str)` to import the JSON string as it is (i.e., with double quotes). Yes `json_normalize()` become problematic, but my focus here was to question whether the way pd.read_json() works is correct? Given, IMO it should cast it directly to a `str` without first  importing it as `dict`. And I tried casting to `str` because expected the double quotes to remain as in the original JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `pd.read_json()` may be importing the nested JSON data as a Python `dict` before it is cast to `str`.

You are totally right. The dtype `str` is applied after the json was loaded as a python data structure by the `JsonReader` class. What you get is the string representation of a `dict` and not the raw JSON.

```
import json

d = {"key": "value"}
```

```
>>> d
{'key': 'value'}

>>> str(s)  # dtype=str
"{'key': 'value'}"

>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"key": "value"}'

>>> json.loads(json.dumps(d))
{'key': 'value'}
```

Another example:

```
d = {"key1": "value1", "key2": {"key21": "value21"}}
l = [d] * 3
```

```
>>> df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(l)); print(df)

     key1                  key2
0  value1  {'key21': 'value21'}
1  value1  {'key21': 'value21'}
2  value1  {'key21': 'value21'}

>>> type(df.iloc[0, 1])
dict

>>> df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(l), dtype={'key2': str}); print(df)

     key1                  key2
0  value1  {'key21': 'value21'}  # same display output
1  value1  {'key21': 'value21'}
2  value1  {'key21': 'value21'}

>>> type(df.iloc[0, 1])
str  # but not the same type
```

To get double quotes, use `pd.read_json` without `dtype` and apply `json.dumps` to `dict` columns:

```
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(l))
df['key2'] = df['key2'].apply(json.dumps)
```

```
>>> df

     key1                  key2
0  value1  {"key21": "value21"}
1  value1  {"key21": "value21"}
2  value1  {"key21": "value21"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, is this behaviour correct for `pd.read_json()`? I would have imagined it should not be casting multiple times thereby essentially destroying information (i.e., the double quotes). Would you say this should be changed in some sort of future release?

Comment: JSON is not a valid data type for Python, it have to [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) the whole file in base type (str, dict, list, ...) first to understand the sense of data. For Python, simple or double quotes are not significant, it's just a visual representation and allowing the serialization (pickle). Besides, if your string contains a simple quote, Python prints it with double quotes to enclose the string. I think this behaviour will never be changed.