# Calling cross domain asmx web service using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, web-services

I have written a web service. I am calling this web service using JavaScript. I am calling this from different domain. For that I have added `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` property in the web service. From JavaScript I am calling the service using **XMLHttpRequest**. I tested it using Firefox and everything was fine when. But it was not working in IE.

After some searching I found that this is an issue related to **Cross domain calling**. I have gone through some of the questions posted here. And then I did the following changes in my code -

1. From javaScript I am now calling the service using **XDomainRequest**.
2. I have added following lines befor the return statements in the web-service - `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); 
   return result;`

It is still working fine in firefox. but in IE8 (as per my knowledge, XDomainRequest will not work in lower versions of IE) it is showing error (**XDomainRequest.onerror**).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The crux of your problem in IE is that XDomainRequest doesn't support the pre-flighting necessary to make a cross-domain request that includes a Content-Type header. I believe that's fixed in IE10, but [even IE9 doesn't fully support CORS](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors).

To reliably make cross-domain requests to ScriptServices in browsers that don't support CORS well, [a server-side proxy](http://encosia.com/use-asp-nets-httphandler-to-bridge-the-cross-domain-gap/) is (unfortunately) your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Look into JSONP (json with padding).

Question about JSONP:
[jsonp with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery)

Has some more info about it: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The type of service that he's using does not support JSONP.

Answer (score -1):

your web service runs over HTTP right?

I don't recommend using the native XMLHttpRequest to make ajax request, maybe you should use [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to do this, I always do in that way and works in all modern browsers:

i.e:

```
function Activate(EmailId, controle) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Page/Method",
        data: "&EmailId=" + EmailId,
        success: function (message) {
            $(controle).text(message);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: to make cross-domain requests you can use the [James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) plug-In, and do something like this:

```
$('#container').load('http://google.com');

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://news.bbc.co.uk',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var headline = $(res.responseText).find('a.tsh').text();
        alert(headline);
    }
});
```

Comment: he's trying to make a cross domain request - this won't work.  Plus, jQuery just wraps XHR.

Comment: It's important to understand that James' plugin there is using YQL to bounce the requests through a public third party that augments them with JSONP support, not actually solving the underlying cross-origin issue.