# Jsonp with parameters

Tags: jsonp

This example works fine (without parameters):
[JSONP sample on twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery)

```
<html><head><title>Twitter 2.0</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<div id='tweet-list'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/codinghorror.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets) {
        for(i in tweets) {
            tweet = tweets[i];
            $("#tweet-list").append(tweet.text + "<hr />");
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

But it doesn't work with this url:

```
var url = "https://thiswaschangedforsecurity/Rest/Authenticate/Login?username=jsm&password=a&ip=1";
```

This url returns json data when paste on url bar:

```
{"SessionID":"44e6f809-3b40-43fc-b425-069e9c52cbda","SourceIP":"1","UserID":313}
```

But I can't make it work with JSONP. Any idea about this?

Comment: Did my answer not fix your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable jsonp (causes cross-domain access), this should be put inside web.config file

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
      ....
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(tweets) {
```

is appending a ? to your url when it should be adding a & since, in the problem case, your url already has a ?