# To suppress popup on IE 'This page is accessing information..........' through code

Tags: jquery

I want cross domain data access for my project and I made it work but I am stuck with this popup which says `This page is accessing information.` I don't want to suppress it by explicitly changing browser settings: can I modify my working code to suppress this message?

My working code with popup:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">$.ajax({
     url: "http://sys85/testservice/serviceCall.ashx",
    dataType: "text",
    type: 'get',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (window.console) console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);

    }
});
</script>
```

I have tried with the example given here: [jsonp with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery), but for my URL it doesn't work .

My handler file to return result (serviceCall.ashx):

```
string result = "121";
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
context.Response.Write(result);
```

Do I have to make any changes with my handler file?

When I try to add an error function to get error details:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = "http://sys85/testservice/serviceCall.ashx";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    })
    .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
        document.getElementById('lblmsg').value = "Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown;
    })
});
```

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'error'`.

Tried every possible ways to get rid of this message.

Answer (score 0):

Use the error callback in jquerys `$.ajax` method instead, just like in your first example.

AFAIK, `getJSON` has no error callback, and is just shorthand for `$.ajax` with dataType set to 'json'