# getJSON - why it didnt work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Why getJSON method works only with local files? If I want to take json from local it works, but if I set url with http it doesnt work. why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        $.getJSON("http://www.address.com/getTables.php", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, table) {
                $("#tables").append("<p>" + table.id + " " + table.tabname + "</p>");
            });
        });
    </script>

    <body>
        <div id="tables"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Returned JSON:

```
[{ "id":"12", "tabname":"cukry" }, { "id":"11", "tabname":"table" }]
```

Comment: Can you show us your `getTables.php` code?  And also what *does* happen when you attempt to execute `$.getJSON`?  Maybe use Chrome's developer tools and look at the Network tab or the console.

Comment: gettables.php php is correct, it returns Json. If I take a simply Json file by http it doesnt work too (http://www.address.com/test.json). Whats wrong? I only want to show this JSON file

Comment: What *does* happen when you attempt to submit the request with `$.getJSON`?  Check Chrome's developer tool's console and network tab.

Comment: If you are using local files, then you shouldn't be mentioning HTTP address unless the codes are inside a server like WAMP.

Comment: Is address.com your domain? Does all the code run on this domain? If not, you need JSONP, not JSON.

Comment: It was a problem with different domains, i didnt know that before. thanks a lot edwardmp :)

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2686406/586621) related to JSONP

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're probably running into the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: GET http://pkr.mydevil.net/panel/actions/getTables.php
 
200 OK
  154ms 
jquery-latest.js (wiersz 8240)
NagłówkiHTML
Nagłówki odpowiedzi
Connection keep-alive
Content-Type text/html
Date Tue, 26 Jun 2012 12:47:31 GMT
Server nginx
Transfer-Encoding chunked
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.11
Nagłówki zapytania
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Connection keep-alive
Host pkr.mydevil.net
Origin null
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1 FirePHP/0.7.1
x-insight activate

Answer (score 0):

Like Matt said it`s because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Try using JSONP. You just need to add callback to your request URL like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.address.com/getTables.php?jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, table) {
            $("#tables").append("<p>" + table.id + " " + table.tabname + "</p>");
        });
    });
```

See more about JSONP [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)