# why this URL is not coming under same origin policy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-domain, jsonp

What I have learnt about JSON-P (from [JSON-P VS JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2887218/778687) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)) is - JSON-P is invented to overcome the [same origin policy of browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) and load JSON objects from another domain. There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686406/778687) on stackoverflow which shows how JSON-P calls work. There it seems, if I remove `?callback=?` from the URL, the JSON-P request acts like plain JSON call and hence rejected by same origin policy. Which is proved by [this live example](http://jsfiddle.net/4HXyJ/) .

Now I have another URL : `https://graph.facebook.com/100001612121705.json`
And I use following method to load data from it ([visit here for live example](http://jsfiddle.net/yq9Bb/1/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/100001612121705", null,
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) { 
            alert(key + ' is ' + val);
        });
    });
});​
```

Note that I am not using the `?callback?` with my URL and still this request is able fetch JSON data from another domain ! Which is very surprising to me. Can anyone kindly explain why is this request not rejected by Same Origin Rule ?

Comment: The jsFiddle you refer to is using: "?callback=?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook's server emits a header of

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This header is retrieved by the browser in the first phase of the call and parsed, it states that any referrer (origin page) may load data from that url. Thus bypassing the same-origin-policy restrictions.

Info on the standards here:

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Answer (score 7):

It's because the HTTP-response contains this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

The `*` means that any origin may retrieve the given resource via XHR (Ajax).

So, if you have a resource on your web-server, and you want to make it available via XHR regardless of origin, just add the above header to the HTTP-response.

Comment: Thank you Šime Vidas , and @BobDavies for clearing my doubts. Both of you have already got my vote. I am accepting Bob's answer as he needs more reputation. Thanks guys :)