# how to display jqgrid from url (local data works, url data does not)

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have looked various question/answers on stackoverflow, but haven't found a solution.

When I use the first block of jqgrid code (data is local), the table and the data are displayed.

When I use the second block (data loaded from url), an empty table is displayed.

The strange part is that the local data is the actual content of the url file.
So I had assumed that the behavior would be identical.

Why can I not display the data using the url, 
when the same data, if copied into the code, is displayed?

The HTML (calls mytest.js which contains the jqgrid code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="ui.jqgrid.css" />
   <script src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
   <script src="grid.locale-en.js"></script>    
   <script src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
   <script src="mytest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>hey</h1>
  <table id="jqgrid"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON as local data (data displays, [here, edited for brevity]):

```
var mydata = [
         {"_id": {"$oid": "50a3f962b7718da1a3090fa9"}, 
         "config": {"titlepage": 
                      {"title": "My First Title",
                       "color": true,
                       "fontsize": "42/44",
                      }
                   }
         },
         {"_id": {"$oid": "50a3f962b7718da1a3090faa"}, 
         "config": {"titlepage": 
                      {"title": "My Second Title",
                       "color": true,
                       "fontsize": "42/44",
                      }
                   }
         }
         ];
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jqgrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: mydata,
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems : false,
        },
        caption: 'Titlepage Parameters',
        colNames: ['title', 'color','fontsize'],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'config.titlepage.title'},
            {name: 'config.titlepage.color'},
            {name: 'config.titlepage.fontsize'},
        ],
    });
});
```

JSON via URL (no data displayed). The file mydata.json contains the same data 
that is used above, but in a local file instead of in the actual js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jqgrid').jqGrid({
        url:'mydata.json',
        datatype:"json",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems : false,
    },
    caption: 'Titlepage Parameters',
    colNames: ['title', 'color','fontsize'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'config.titlepage.title'},
        {name: 'config.titlepage.color'},
        {name: 'config.titlepage.fontsize'},
    ],
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this the cross-site scripting JSONP problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery when you use your debugger, is there anything being blocked in the "network" section?

Comment: no, the json data is there, it just is not displayed in the grid. The html, the js and the json file are all served from the same apache instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would fix a little your first version of working code. `jsonReader` will be *not* used if you use `jsonReader`. Instead of that it will be used [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data). Additionally I would recommend you always use native `id` values if the input data have such one. So I would fix the code to the following:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var mydata = [
            {
                "_id": {"$oid": "50a3f962b7718da1a3090fa9"},
                "config": {
                    "titlepage": {
                        "title": "My First Title",
                        "color": true,
                        "fontsize": "42/44"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "_id": {"$oid": "50a3f962b7718da1a3090faa"},
                "config": {
                    "titlepage": {
                        "title": "My Second Title",
                        "color": true,
                        "fontsize": "42/44"
                    }
                }
            }
        ];
    $('#jqgrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: mydata,
        caption: 'Titlepage Parameters',
        gridview: true,
        height: 'auto',
        colNames: ['title', 'color', 'fontsize'],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'config.titlepage.title' },
            {name: 'config.titlepage.color' },
            {name: 'config.titlepage.fontsize' },
        ],
        localReader: {
            id: "_id.$oid"
        }
    });
});
```

See [the first demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Tim1.htm).

In case of usage `datatype: "json"` you need to fix the `jsonReader`:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('#jqgrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        url: 'Tim2.json',
        caption: 'Titlepage Parameters',
        gridview: true,
        height: "auto",
        //colNames: ['title', 'color', 'fontsize'],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'title', jsonmap: 'config.titlepage.title' },
            {name: 'color', jsonmap: 'config.titlepage.color' },
            {name: 'fontsize', jsonmap: 'config.titlepage.fontsize' },
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "_id.$oid",
            root: function (obj) {
                return obj;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See [another demo](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Tim2.htm).

Comment: hi Oleg, thanks. I don't understand your second sentence -- jsonReader will not be used when I use ... (datatype: 'local' maybe)?  The major missing piece for me was to use the root function in the jsonReader; once I added that, reading from the url was fine. I'll post the minimal code that loaded the data. thanks!

Comment: @Tim: If you use `datatype: 'local'` then you have to use `localReader` instead of `jsonReader` to configure reading. For example to use `_id.$oid` as rowid you should use `localReader:{id:"_id.$oid"}`. I don't commented other changes which I made in the demo, but all there are recommended. It's better to use `{name: 'title', jsonmap: 'config.titlepage.title' }` as `{name:'config.titlepage.title'}`. The `name` will be used in many cases to build ids or as property of objects. The names with "." could produce errors in some parts of jqGrid code. The usage of `gridview: true` improve performance

Comment: I understand now. I will put all your changes into my final page--the performance and behavior is important! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Oleg's answer is the full solution.

Here is the modified code which works. That is, the code I originally wrote plus the one change (from Oleg) that successfully loaded the data into the grid. The key for me was to add the root function in jsonReader:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#jqgrid').jqGrid({
        url:'mydata.json',
        datatype:"json",
        jsonReader: {
            root: function (obj) { return obj; },
            repeatitems : false,
        },
        caption: 'Titlepage Parameters',
        colNames: ['title', 'color','fontsize'],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'config.titlepage.title'},
            {name: 'config.titlepage.color'},
            {name: 'config.titlepage.fontsize'},
        ],
    });
});
```