# jQuery ajax, get html cross domain

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a webpage where I am trying to use an ajax call to place some html content from another webpage inside. However I am struggling with the cross domain issues.

```
$('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myothersite.com',
        datatype: 'text/html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            var content = data.responseText;
            console.log(content);
        }
    });
});
```

Would anyone be able to advise how I would go about achieving this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

You **cannot** do a cross domain get of `text/html` in any modern browser.

The only return type that I know of that works currently is `jsonp`

---

Or you can do some [cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: @MattBall yes that too. I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you can adjust the headers appropriately, you can perform cross-origin requests.

In order for it to work you need to change the client and the server:

Client:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"];
```

Client using jQuery

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

The server needs to be changed to in order to respond to the `OPTIONS` request appropriately. I have written [an example for ASP.NET Web API](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201211/Blog/Using-CORS-With-ASP-NET-Web-API/), but the concepts are the same no matter what you are running on the server.

If you cannot make the changes to the server (for example it is a third party service) you can still use [old-school JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery).

Comment: Does setting `jQuery.support.cors` to `true`; actually solve anything? IE6 7 for example do not support cors and cannot support cors, and IE8 can't support it with $.ajax unless you make changes to $.ajax.

Comment: If you don't set it to true, CORS won't work in any browser. CORS works by sending an OPTIONS pre-request and validating the response, before then sending the actual request. CORS is definitely a "new browser" technology.

Comment: For example, In chrome and firefox, `$.support.cors` is `true` because "withCredentials" is present in the xhr object.

Comment: IE8 and 9 both use `XDomainRequest` for CORS requests, which jQuery purposely doesn't use. Source: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283