# Ajax cross-domain request with JSONP

Tags: jquery

I am using JSONP in order to make a AJAX Cross domain call as following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#btnWCFREST").click(function () {
          $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "http://localhost:1415/MyService.svc/rh/data?id=4&callback=mycallback",
                  processData: false,
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
                  jsonp: 'callback'


              });


          });
      });

      function mycallback(data) {
          alert(data);
      };
```

I am not getting any response. Could anybody help me in order to resolve the issue? What is wrong with the call?

I have changed the call as following still no luck:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#btnWCFREST").click(function () {
                 var url = "http://localhost:1415/MyService.svc/rh/data?id=4";
                  $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
         });
      });
```

Comment: have a look at http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/adelkhalil/archive/2009/08/14/cross-domain-jsonp-with-jquery-call-step-by-step-guide.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's `ajax` documentation [says](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Your url doesn't meet that requirement, so it's treated as a *JSON* (instead of *JSONP*) request, which will be subject to the limit of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You may refer to a working example on Stackoverflow: [jsonp with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery). Besides, you should make sure that the cross-domain server supports JSONP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. According to the working example provided in the above line, I have changed the call as following but no luck:                             $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#btnWCFREST").click(function () {
                     var url = "http://localhost:1415/MyService.svc/rh/data?id=4";
                      $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    });
             });
          });

Comment: Does the service provided by `MyService.svc` support JSONP? It's supposed to return the feedback whose payload is something like `mycallback(requested JSON data)`.

Comment: Its a WCF REST service and returning  JSON as data. Do I need to perform anything addtional at service end?

Comment: You shouldn't return plain JSON as feedback data. Instead, return something like `mycallback({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7})`. Please refer to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `crossDomain : true` in your Ajax settings :

```
       $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://localhost:1415/MyService.svc/rh/data?id=4&callback=mycallback",
              processData: false,
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
              jsonp: 'callback',
              crossDomain: true
       });
```