# jQuery jsonp not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am trying to implement jsonp with jQuery but it is not working I did see the example in [jsonp with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery)

But in my case it is always making ajax call I am appending `&callback=?` at the end

I construct relative url like

```
var url="/pbs/getTraits.do"+ $('#pbstraits').serialize()+"&callback=?";

$.getJSON(url, null, function(data){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = data.message;
    });
```

is this the right way of doing it?

Also when I am sending query parameters along with url I have to encode which is the best way to do it.

Comment: You don't need JSONP for your own domain.

Comment: but why its not working

Comment: How is it not working? What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: it is doing an xhr request instead of script request

Answer (score 1):

jQuery looks for `=?` *in the querystring*.
Your URL doesn't have a querystring.  (it has no `?`)

Instead, you should write

```
$.getJSON("/pbs/getTraits.do?callback=?"", $('#pbstraits').serialize(), ...);
```

Comment: thanks i did  what u said but still not change final url generated was http://localhost:9080/pbs/getTrait.do?callback=jsonp1362757897550&_=1362757900035&traitName=sine&traitValue=junk