# ajax form submits fine, but success does not work?

Tags: ajax

I have a simple form that submits with jquery and ajax.  the form submits fine and the data posts, but the success message will not call... just the error message. can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".form-submit").click(function() {                        
var esn = $("#esn").val();

var dataString = 'esn='+esn;

if(esn=='')
{
$('.error').show().fadeOut(3000);
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "include/submit_repair_form.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(result) {
    alert(result);  
    $('.testing').hide(); 
  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    alert(xhr.statusText);
  }   
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the `result` variable in `function()`

Like this:

```
success: function(result) {
    alert(result);  
    $('.testing').hide(); 
  }
```

Comment: Try `console.log(result);` instead of `alert(result);`. You might get some extra info

Comment: the script for the form is called on another server... does that matter?

Comment: k so in order to get a success result the url: has to be on the same server?

Comment: Yes, and you can't use post... Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery