# ajax post error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post

I have the following ajax post:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://192.168.7.9/api",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { username: "john.doe", password: "123456", method: "search_samples" },
    success: function ( data ) {
       // Never get here
    },
    error: function ( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        // Always here: if async true, errorThrown has no message
        // otherwise I se the NETWORK_ERR message
    }
} );
```

It is returning with this error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101.

I have read a bunch of SO posts on this error, most suggest that I set async to true.  This DOES remove the error message- but it is still an error, and I never get valid data.  It just seems to remove the error message which is not helpful.

In fiddler, on the same dev machine this works perfectly- is this a chrome issue?  An origin issue?  Is something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Is this a cross domain request (i.e. is your main application not running at `http://192.168.7.9`)?

Comment: @Steve These machines are on the same subnet, but the 192.168.7.9 machine isn't in a domain at all...

Answer (score 1):

OK, it looks like you are running into issues with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  The way you are doing it, you can't access AJAX data from a different server than the one that is hosting your application.

To do so, you would either have to move the `http://192.168.7.9/api` functionality onto your server or use JSONP to transfer the data. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery) is an example of how to do so.

Comment: So far no luck- I am trying to use jsonp as described, but I now get the following error: `jQuery19108882399478461593_1364424507799 was not called`.  I think I read someplace the server itself has to support jsonp?  Maybe that's whats going on?