# Calling Servlet using Jquery

Tags: jquery, servlets

I am trying to retrieve from a servlet using Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mybutton").click(function(event) {
        alert('1');
        $.get("http://localhost:8888/ntlm/getuser", function(data) {
            alert('data ' + data);
            $(".errorMssg").text("Data Loaded: " + data);
            alert('data ' + data);
        });
        return true;
    });
});
```

and in GetUser servlet I have

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, 
                                                       IOException {
    response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
            response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("Authenticating?");
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, 
                                                           IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

If I directly access `http://localhost:8888/ntlm/getuser`, I am able to see output, however when I calling using Jquery, not able to see the output.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: @alkis Response is empty.

Comment: What does *empty* mean? You see `alert('data')` twice?

Comment: @PaulGrime I do not see `alert('data')`

Comment: Is the web page also on `http://localhost:8888`? Otherwise the browser will stop a cross-domain request (without special exception). Is the request sent? Does the server receive the request?

Comment: @PaulGrime I am calling the servlet which is not in the same context. It is deployed as another application

Comment: And the other questions?

Comment: @PaulGrime Request has been sent, however it doesn't looks like it received the request.

Comment: Can you confirm there are no JS errors in the console and that the Ajax request is leaving the browser as expected - correct url etc? And that when you copy and paste that URL into another browser window that it works?

Comment: Dont use the whole path.. Just use the `<url-pattern>` that you have mentioned in your `web.xml` or in the annotation.

Comment: @PaulGrime There are no JS errors and when I am directly accessing my servlet I am able to see the output.

Comment: @PaulGrime I can see the following in chrome  console though `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8888/ntlm/authenticate. Origin http://192.168.1.2:8988 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: I asked if the web page was on the same protocol, host and port as the Ajax request and you said yes, but that isn't the case. This is a cross domain issue.

Comment: @PaulGrime How to deal with this? Any workaround?

Comment: If 192.168.1.2 is an alias for localhost (i.e. it's your machine's IP) then strip the protocol, host and port from the Ajax and just use `/ntlm/getuser`. If the `/ntlm/getuser` resource is genuinely on a different server than your web pages, then you have to use CORS, or JSONP, or change your design.

Comment: @PaulGrime How I can use JSONP to resolve my problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery

Comment: @PaulGrime Thanks for this, in my case what will be the callback?

Comment: Nothing. The `callback=?` part of the requested URL is a signal to jQuery to use JSONP, and provided your server response is in a JSONP compatible format, then your callback will be called. Read the linked answer and the jQuery docs carefully.

Comment: @PaulGrime Thanks a lot for pointing out the problem and suggesting the correct example, I have resolved the issue. If you could post an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform cross-domain requests, e.g. a request to `http://localhost:8888/ntlm/authenticate` from a web page served from `http://192.168.1.2:8988`, you will either need to enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or use JSONP.

[jQuery JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery).

Comment: Thanks Paul for your solution.