# Cross Domain ajax request with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to make a cross domain ajax request using json`

```
$(function() {
    $(".x25").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/select",
                processData: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json",
                jsonp: false,
                data: {
                    q: "name:" + request.term + "*",
                    wt: "xslt",
                    tr: "solr2json.xsl"
                },
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function() {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This is my code, i am keep trying with json and jsonp but did not get succeed and i dont have any control on remote server. Any help.

Comment: What is the meaning of using `jsonp: false` & `dataType : "jsonp"` together, in your code above??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery

Comment: @Palash Ohh.. its my mistake though i remove that it is not working

Comment: error message? Cross domain shouldn't affect you here, you can retrieve data from anywhere as long as the requested host + port + protocol match the response host + port + protocol

Comment: @user2503916 remove the `crossDomain: true, jsonp:false`

Comment: @TecHunter i am getting SyntaxError: syntax error <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> in my firebug

Comment: @user2503916 that's because you get a XML response from your server and not a jsonp response. open this in your browser `http://localhost:8983/solr/select?name=test*&wt=xslt&tr=solr2json.xsl` what do you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for this, it was my mistake in understanding solr response. As i was requesting it for solr response it does not require any .xslt or xslt2json. I can directly get the response by making ws: json in my ajax request.

```
 $(function() {
    $(".x25").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/select",
                processData: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json",
                jsonp: false,
                data: {
                    q: "name:" + request.term + "*",
                    wt: "json"
                },
                success: function() {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your JS:

```
 <script>            
      jQuery.support.cors = true;
      $(document).ready(function(){
          //stuff
      }
 </script>
```

Comment: It didn't work. i just added this line just before my function call

Comment: I usually add it before the jquery code. (updated the answer) What is your error message by the way_

Comment: I am getting below error in my firebug console SyntaxError: syntax error

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: That is the response already, which is invalid and also not JSON, but XML. An invalid XML that is...

Comment: Can you please elaborate what causes that error and where i am going wrong

Comment: The response form the server is probably not a valid xml. As it is a SOLR search server, I assume you don't have much affect on that one. You should check the actual server response with Fiddler or with some tool. Also if you could update the code you are using right now, that would help the community to help you...

Comment: You might want to read this http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler as you can get JSON response too... If you still have issue you should raise another question as it is a SOLR thing from this point and not jquery...

Comment: Thank you but i am successfully getting the json data from solr when i try from a java file the issue  i am facing is integrating it with textbox which is in my ui page

Comment: I'm no export of the SOLR REST(?) search, but you might need `wt=json` in the request to get a json response. I don't know if the xml and xslt way is necessary or what that is, it seems easier to request a json....

Comment: Yup you are right Banlint. I have been mis guided and i fixed it now and it is working fine Thank you very much for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/select",
   dataType: 'jsonp'
    data: {
           q: "name:" + request.term + "*",
           wt: "xslt",
           tr: "solr2json.xsl"
          },
    success: function() {
           alert("Success");
    },
    error: function() {
            alert("failure");
    }
});
```

**Try this out this**

Answer (score 0):

```
dataType : 'jsonp',
jsonp : 'json.wrf',
```