# Get JSON via javascript [Cross-Domain]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Please help me with the following situation:

there is the page p1.aspx with only one button:

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="btnclick();">Button</button>    
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#btn1').click(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/p2.aspx", function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (i, field) {            
        alert(field);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Above is how I want to get the JSON text via javascript.

Web application `http://localhost/p2.aspx` is redirected to `http://localhost/p3.aspx` inside. And the page `http://localhost/p3.aspx` again is redirected back to 
`http://localhost/p2.aspx?code=1`.

```
code=1
```

is the value I want read in my javascript code. But it's not works.

In p2.aspx I generate JSON data as following

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(jsonString);
Response.End();
```

After this I can not read json data via javascript. But if I just put the  `http://localhost/p2.aspx` via web browser then it get json data on the page.

Comment: Try using a relative URL ie just `/p2.aspx`

Comment: The cause is that p2.aspx will be placed on my server but p3.aspx and p1.aspx will be placed on foreign servers

Comment: What is the value of `jsonString`?

Comment: the value for `jsonstring` is {
flag: "1"
} just the simple value to try get json object

Comment: So your trying to get cross domain json then. Thats the sort of thing you need to mention in your question. You read the *dataType* section here  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use crossDomain

Comment: It's not working. @asawyer can you please give more information about how I should setup ajax request to use cross domain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery

Comment: @asawyer thanks for link but I have added `?callback=?` to my url and set the following `$.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: true
      });` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Now there is the following in javascript console `Error: SyntaxError: invalid label
Source Code:
{"flag":"1"}`

Comment: @sancoma: Using `crossDomain` and/or adding `?callback=?` doesn't magically make it work.  You need to make sure the server supports it.  If you add `?callback=?`, you're requesting JSONP.  This means you should return a JavaScript file (`application/javascript`) using the callback param as a function call: like `$_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');'` (I use PHP, adapt to your language).  Or use CORS, by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the server (http://enable-cors.org/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) if you want that to work.

So your script should take into account the `callback` parameter:

```
Response.Clear();
string callback = Request["callback"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callback))
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/javascript; charset=utf-8";
    Response.Write(string.Format("{0}({1})", callback, jsonString));
}
else
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Response.Write(jsonString);
}
Response.End();
```

And then on the client:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/p2.aspx?callback=?", function (data) {
    ...
});
```

Notice how the `callback` query string parameter is set to `?`. Basically jQuery will translate this to a request that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/p2.aspx?callback=jQuery123456789....
```

and your server side script should of course return `JSONP` which is your `JSON` string wrapped into the callback name:

```
jQuery123456789....({"code":1})
```

Also make sure that the `jsonString` variable used in your code is an actual JSON string (as its name suggests). Because what you have shown in your question (`code=1`) is very far from being JSON.

Comment: If you are using JSONP, the correct `Content-type` to send with the response should be `application/javascript`.  JSONP is actually just a JavaScript file, that's appended to your page.

Comment: You are perfectly correct. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem.  Some browsers might've got mad about that :-P

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Have I mentioned lately how much I love you?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Sorry for misprint but I have posted an incorrect scenario how it should works. The correct scenario is:

Web application p2.aspx is redirected to p3.aspx inside. And the page p3.aspx again is redirected back to p2.aspx.
And into this p2.aspx I generate the JSON data. So I do not provide JSON data in url as a parameter for p2.aspx.

Comment: @sancoma, this doesn't matter. No matter how many redirects you are doing, at the end of the day you should return JSONP as shown in my answer if you want to be able to do cross domain AJAX calls.