# javascript fetch returns a stream and content wrapped in a callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, stream, fetch

Looking for the best way to access the data returned from an api call. The string looks like this:

```
'https://somedomain/data.json?callback=someCallback'
```

and I fetch like this:

```
fetch('https://somedomain/data.json?callback=someCallback')
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => console.log(text));
```

and this will give me the data that I need but it wrapped up in the callback like so:

```
someCallback({/* json like data here */})
```

I know the returned data is a stream because if I do soemthing like this:

```
.then(response => {
     const reader = response.body.getReader();
     console.log(reader);
});
```

I get back this:

```
ReadableStreamDefaultReader {closed: Promise}
```

Ideally I would like this data in the form of a json object so how would I go about getting that. Or if that is just bad practice how to read this?

Comment: Have you tried `response.json()`?

Comment: yes but since the response is not a json object this gives an error. The response is a readable stream.

Comment: Looks like this is a jsonp question. This issue helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246873/how-to-do-cross-domain-jsonp-request-in-javascript