# Problems passing '?' in URL to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an Ajax call to weatherunderground.
The code is:

```
$(".city").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        // GET http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=San%20F
        url: "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            name_startsWith: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.RESULTS, function( item ) {
            return {
                label: item.name + item.countryName,
                value: item.name
            };
        }));
     }
 });
},
minLength: 2,
select: function( event, ui ) {
   log( ui.item ?
      "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
       "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
 },
 open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
 },
 close: function() {
   $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
   }
 });
```

No matter how I treat the question mark following aq I get an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :' error. If I encode the ? as '?' I get &? in the resulting URL. If I remove the ampersand the request functions correctly.
If I use either encodeURL() on the entire string or encodeURLComponent of the ? the results are %3F which doesn't work either.

I am ready to tear my hair out, does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Add `type: "GET",` before the line with `url:`

Comment: Why don't you simply put the `query` parameter in the `data` object as everything else?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: JSONP is always GET anyway.

Comment: Yeah - I just saw where the OP said "jsonp" @Bergi. I had missed that before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsonp with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

The error actually stems from a mismatched parameter name rather than the `?` in the `url`.

The parameter at issue is the one that specifies the JSONP callback:

```
http://.../aq?query=San%20F&callback=jQuery111___140___&ts=12345
//                          ^^^^^^^^
```

And, jQuery's default name of `callback` [isn't what the API is expecting](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=autocomplete-api#options):

```
cb           JSONP callback method name
```

To change the parameter, you can include `jsonp: 'cb'` in the request options.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=San%20F",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: 'cb',

    // ...
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/X2JEA/

---

And, the syntax error is from the response. Without a `cb` parameter, the service is responding with JSON, lacking the "*Padding*" to make it JSONP.

```
{"RESULTS": ...}
//        ^ syntax error
```

```
jQuery111___140___({"RESULTS": ... });
// with padding
```

Note that JSONP is actually JavaScript and is requested with a `<script>` element. It's just taking advantage of the 2 languages' similarities in syntax. But, it needs the padding to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. (I know I'm not supposed to say that but nonetheless...)

The answer was two fold:
As mentioned above the callback line that needed `jsonp: 'cb',

as well as the data portion instead of:

```
name_startsWith: request.term
```

it needed:

```
query: request.term
```

I did not understand the correct syntax for the data section.